# Sending and receiving compressed data over a TCP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, compression

Need help with sending and receiving compressed data over TCP socket.

The code works perfectly fine if I don't use compression, but something very strange happens when I do use compression.. Basically, the problem is that the stream.Read() operation gets skipped and I don't know why..

My code:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", 6100);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // SEND REQUEST
        byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

        // send compressed bytes (if this is used, then stream.Read() below doesn't work.
        //var compressedBytes = bytesSent.ToStream().GZipCompress();
        //stream.Write(compressedBytes, 0, compressedBytes.Length);

        // send normal bytes (uncompressed)
        stream.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length);

        // GET RESPONSE
        byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        // PROBLEM HERE: when using compression, this line just gets skipped over very quickly
        stream.Read(bytesReceived, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        //var decompressedBytes = bytesReceived.ToStream().GZipDecompress();
        //string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived);

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

You will notice some extension methods above. Here is the code in case you are wondering if something is wrong there.

```
public static MemoryStream ToStream(this byte[] bytes)
{
    return new MemoryStream(bytes);
}


public static byte[] GZipCompress(this Stream stream)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(gZipStream);
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] GZipDecompress(this Stream stream)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gZipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The extensions work quite well in the following, so I'm sure they're not the problem:

```
string original = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
byte[] compressedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original).ToStream().GZipCompress();
byte[] decompressedBytes = compressedBytes.ToStream().GZipDecompress();
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Does anyone have any idea why the Read() operation is being skipped when the bytes being sent are compressed?

**EDIT**

I received a message from the API provider after showing them the above sample code. They had this to say:

> at a first glance I guess the header is missing. The input must start
>   with a 'c' followed by the length of the input
>   (sprintf(cLength,"c%09d",hres) in our example). We need this because
>   we can't read until we find a binary 0 to recognize the end.

They previously provided some sample code in `C`, which I don't fully understand 100%, as follows:

```
example in C:

#include <zlib.h>

uLongf hres;
char cLength[COMPRESS_HEADER_LEN + 1] = {'\0'};

n = read(socket,buffer,10);
// check if input is compressed
if(msg[0]=='c') {
     compressed = 1;
}

n = atoi(msg+1);
read.....


hres = 64000;
res = uncompress((Bytef *)msg,   &hres, (const Bytef*) 
buffer/*compressed*/, n);
if(res == Z_OK && hres > 0 ){
     msg[hres]=0; //original
}
else // errorhandling

hres = 64000;

if (compressed){
res = compress((Bytef *)buffer,   &hres, (const Bytef *)msg, strlen(msg));
     if(res == Z_OK && hres > 0 ) {
         sprintf(cLength,"c%09d",hres);
         write(socket,cLength,10);
         write(socket, buffer, hres);
     }
     else // errorhandling

makefile: add "-lz" to the libs
```

They're using zlib. I don't suspect that to make any difference, but I did try using zlib.net and I still get no response anyway.

Can someone give me an example of how exactly I'm supposed to send this input length in C#?

**EDIT 2**

In response to @quantdev, here is what I am trying now for the length prefix:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", 6100);
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // SEND REQUEST
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        byte[] compressedBytes = ZLibCompressor.Compress(bytes);

        byte[] prefix = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("c" + compressedBytes.Length);

        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[prefix.Length + compressedBytes.Length];
        Array.Copy(prefix, bytesToSend, prefix.Length);
        Array.Copy(compressedBytes, 0, bytesToSend, prefix.Length, compressedBytes.Length);

        stream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        // WAIT
        while (client.Available == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        // GET RESPONSE
        byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        stream.Read(bytesReceived, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        byte[] decompressedBytes = ZLibCompressor.DeCompress(bytesReceived);
        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by skipped over ? what is the length of bytesReceived after the call ?

Comment: What I mean by skipped over is that it just executes that line in no time whatsoever and moves onto the next line. If I don't use compression, the app waits there at `stream.Read()` for about 60 seconds or so until there is data before it continues on

Comment: You should verify the return value of the Read() call before proceeding. Also, have you considered an Async Client ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the [return value of the Read() calls you are making on the TCP stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.read): it is the number of bytes effectively read.

MSDN says :

> **Return Value**
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number  of bytes requested if that many bytes are not
>   currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been
>   reached.

- If the socket is closed, the call will return immediately 0 (which is what might be happening here).
- If is not 0, then you **must** check how many bytes you did actually received, if it is less than `client.ReceiveBufferSize`, you will need additional calls to `Read` to retrieve the remaining bytes.

Prior to you call to read, check that some data is actually [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the socket :

```
while(client.Available == 0)
// wait ...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @quantdev but using `while(client.Available == 0)` seems to just make it go into an infinite loop. I waited about 3 minutes before giving up..

Comment: Yes, because nobody is sending anything to your socket. This is why you need to check it : ) (and also to avoid those polling loops, go for Async Sockeets)

Comment: thanks - it looks like the API provider is not sending anything if the data is compressed and it seems I need to send some input length along with the request. Please see my edit in the main post above and if you could help, that would be great.

Comment: @Matt, prepend to the bytesSentArray  the 'c' character followed by the length (as a unsigned long) of `bytesSent` (before prepending). This is basically what they are asking you. Btw my first answer to your first question was eventually correct, no ? ; )

Comment: Regarding your first answer, I'm not really sure if it's correct, because without compression it was working fine.. what happened is that (because it's synchronous) it was simply waiting for a response (usually about 60 seconds) and then continued. I did not need to specifically tell it to wait. But I have implemented that suggestion in any case.. but like I said I don't know if it's correct because when I test it with the compressed data, I get no response and end up waiting forever. I will implement async sockets later as well, but I want to get a simple example working first.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion above for prepending, I have just tried that. Thanks. However, it doesn't seem to work either. Maybe I am doing it wrong though, so I will edit my answer above to show what I am doing.  :-)

Comment: Please see my edit. Does it seem as though I am prepending the length correctly? Or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have the end of file or so. Can you try setting the stream position before reading the stream

```
stream.position = 0;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.read

Answer (score 0):

Encoding.UTF8.GetString shouldn't be used on arbitrary byte array.
e.g.: The compressed bytes may contain NULL character, which is not allowed in UTF-8 encoded text except for being used as terminator.

If you want to print the received bytes for debugging, maybe you should just print them as integers.

Comment: The code doesn't get that far. The problem is at the previous line. As I also said, the code works perfectly fine if the data is not compressed.